# Maptiler and OpenLayers marks don't work well together

Tags: openlayers, vector, markers, maptiler

I am trying to use Maptiler together with OpenLayers. I followed the instructions in MapTiler site and cannot make the markers to show properly ***over*** the map. What happens is that the map features (landscape, ocean, etc) cover the marks. This is of course not what I want, I want the marks over the map.

This is a full sample code, with a single mark (red disk) over Egypt:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="https://cdn.maptiler.com/ol/v6.12.0/ol.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.maptiler.com/ol-mapbox-style/v6.8.3/olms.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.maptiler.com/ol/v6.12.0/ol.css">
  <style>#map {position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;}</style>
 </head>
 <body>

  <div id="map">
   <a href="https://www.maptiler.com" style="position:absolute;left:10px;bottom:10px;z-index:999;"><img src="https://api.maptiler.com/resources/logo.svg" alt="MapTiler logo"></a>
  </div><p><a href="https://www.maptiler.com/copyright/" target="_blank">&copy; MapTiler</a> <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">&copy; OpenStreetMap contributors</a></p>
  
  <script>
   var styleJson = 'https://api.maptiler.com/maps/8e5c080e-13dc-4c72-a2dd-da52e1472fb4/style.json?key=OyiR3umn4C4sQdRFKc2j';
   var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
     constrainResolution: true,
     center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([20, 20]),
     zoom: 3
    })
   });
   olms.apply(map, styleJson);

   var extinctionLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector() });
   var extinctionLayerSource = extinctionLayer.getSource();
   map.addLayer(extinctionLayer);

   var circlered = '<svg width="32" height="32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
       + '<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="14" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="red" /></svg>';

   var extinctionstyle = [
    new ol.style.Style({
     image: new ol.style.Icon({ src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + circlered }),
     zIndex: 0,
    }),
   ];

   var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([30, 30])),
   });

   feature.setStyle(extinctionstyle);
   extinctionLayerSource.addFeature(feature);

  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can see how the ocean covers the mark, and here the map has no features. If you add features like landscape they cover the marks even more.

I tried playing with the `zIndex` of the marks and map canvas without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`olms` works asynchronously so your `extinctionLayer` is added before the base layer.  On option to to set a high `zIndex` on your layer, so it is rendered on top.  A better way is to use the `olms` default method which returns a promise, and add your layer when that resolves:

```
   olms(map, styleJson).then(function() {

     var extinctionLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector() });
     var extinctionLayerSource = extinctionLayer.getSource();
     map.addLayer(extinctionLayer);

     var circlered = '<svg width="32" height="32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">'
       + '<circle cx="16" cy="16" r="14" stroke="yellow" stroke-width="2" fill="red" /></svg>';

     var extinctionstyle = [
       new ol.style.Style({
         image: new ol.style.Icon({ src: 'data:image/svg+xml;utf8,' + circlered }),
         zIndex: 0,
       }),
     ];

     var feature = new ol.Feature({
       geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat([30, 30])),
     });

     feature.setStyle(extinctionstyle);
     extinctionLayerSource.addFeature(feature);

   });
```

Comment: Mmmm... I see. This indeed works in my example. Yet, I need to add marks dynamically using a slider. if I use the `olms(map, styleJson).then(function() ` for the layers only leaving the marks outside, the marks do not appear. I will try to play with your suggestion.

Comment: I managed to make it work. Thanks!!

Comment: BTW, I couldn't make it work using the z-index of the layers.

Comment: Anything greater than 0 worked for me with your original code `var extinctionLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector(), zIndex: 1 });`

Comment: You are right, not sure why it didn't work for me in my 'true' page. Maybe this will be more useful for me after all. Thanks!!!